# tabbarcontroller added programmatically ios but does not open the tabs

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to use a tab bar controller without a navigation controller, and I want it to happen programmatically.

My MainViewController is a subclass of TabBarController and here is the code inside that:

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [self myLikesViewControllerWithTabTitle:@"My Likes" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_feed.png"]],
                            [self mainStreamViewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Stream" image:nil],
                            [self viewControllerWithTabTitle:@"Messages" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_messages.png"]], nil];



    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;

}
```

where :

```
// Create a view controller and setup it's tab bar item with a title and image
-(UIViewController*) viewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*) title image:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image tag:0];
    return viewController;
}

// Create a view controller and setup it's tab bar item with a title and image
-(UIViewController*) myLikesViewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*) title image:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyLikesViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image tag:0];
    return viewController;
}

// Create a view controller and setup it's tab bar item with a title and image
-(UIViewController*) mainStreamViewControllerWithTabTitle:(NSString*) title image:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StreamViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image tag:0];
    return viewController;
}
```

I can see the tabs being created, but no matter what I click, I do not see the XIB's I have created to open.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you use the return value from the viewControllerWithTabTitle:image: method?. Also where and when are you calling that method?

Comment: @rdelmar inside the ViewDidLoad. The ViewController is added in the self.viewControllers array.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. What you have should work as long as your nib names in the methods match your actual names.

Comment: You could have a problem with your images. Are they sized appropriately for an image in a tab bar (they aren't resized for you)? What do you see when you run your app?